# Javascript stylesheet changer changes size of elements on website

Tags: javascript, css, html

So I've added a dark mode theme that I can turn on with a click of a button. A have a javascript that changes the stylesheet with a press of a button:

```
function nightmode(sheet,sheet2) {
  document.getElementById('light1').setAttribute('href', sheet);
  document.getElementById('light2').setAttribute('href', sheet2);
}
```

And buttons which can change the stylesheet

```
<li> <a onclick="nightmode('/cdn/about/css/main_dark.css','/cdn/about/css/bootstrap_dark.css')"  alt="nightmode"> <i class="far fa-moon "></i> </a></li>
<li> <a onclick="nightmode('/cdn/about/css/main.css','/cdn/about/css/bootstrap.css')"  alt="nightmode"> <i class="fas fa-moon "></i> </a></li>
```

But the problem is when I click one of the button the stylesheet changes size of different elements, for example my icon on the website changes. This can be tested on https://swedcraft.net/Game_Hub/ by pressing on the moons. The difference between the two stylesheets are only colors, no sizes.
Thank you!

Comment: Where is 'my icon' ? Be specific... Everything looks perfect to me

Comment: My icon is the (Swedcraft Videos) box when the website loads it has one size and when you press the button it expands. Same with the Games they all resize to be outside the container when the moon is pressed, everything fits before any buttons are pressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

css file has changed the size.For example, this navbar
[image].
First, you do nothing,see the css properties,
[image].
Next,click the moon button and see,padding size has changed,
[image].
So,the stylesheet changes size of different elements.

Comment: Thank you. I did not notice that!

Comment: You are welcome! And when you meet style problems later, you can use the browser debugging.